# Extra information table joined without eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Say I have an database table called Item (with a name and a type). Now depending on the type, the item has extra information: e.g. if it is a ScoredItem it has a Score. So I created a database table ItemScore, which assigns a score to an item.

I then have an eloquent model: Item (with the name and the type), but how should I go about adding this Score property.

An obvious solution would be to create a model: ItemScore and set the correct relation (using hasMany and belongsTo). But because it would only contain a score, this seems a bit overkill.

So the question is: is it possible to somehow specify this relation so that I can request the Score of an item (if it has one) and also set it so that it is correctly saved in the database, without creating this model class?

Comment: Your case is covered with [Polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations). But you will have to create class for your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done with [Polymorphic Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations), *but* you will need to create models to provide the necessary information to Eloquent about the relations. As you said, suppose you have `Item`'s than can have extra information such as `Score` or anything else, let's it can have a `SubItem` instead.

You will have to define those models as shown below:

```php
class Item extends Eloquent
{
    public function extrainfo()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Score extends Eloquent
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Item', 'extrainfo');
    }
}

class SubItem extends Eloquent
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Item', 'extrainfo');
    }
}
```

Then you will have a database structure as follow:

```
items
    id             - integer
    name           - string
    extrainfo_id   - integer
    extrainfo_type - string

scores
    id    - integer
    score - decimal

sub_items
    id   - integer
    name - string
```

This will *automagically* do what you need. When you do:

```php
$extrainfo = $item->extrainfo;
```

The `extrainfo` relation on the `Item` model will return either a `Score` or `SubItem` instance, depending on which type of model owns the photo. That type is defined on the database table.

**Note**: This is not overkill, you can see that as meta information provided to tell Eloquent how to treat your relations.