# How to create a one-to-many relationship in Eloquent to a table without creating a model for that table?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model which holds a property with zero to many values. Those values are strings (e-mail addresses). But I don't want to create an extra model for such values since they only appear in this property.

As far as I read the docs I need to have a model for my e-mail addresses to gain full power of Eloquent.
Am I missing something out or is there no clean way to spare a model for a database table for relationships?

A short example of my database tables in question:

```
Table A:
 - id [serial]
 - name [string]
 - someProperty [string]
 - mailAddresses [unsigned int; reference to id of Table B]

Table B:
 - id [serial]
 - mail [string]
```

I've got a model for Table A:

```
class ModelA extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'Table A';

    public function mailAddresses() {
        return $this->hasMany('<what to put here?>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546933/extra-information-table-joined-without-eloquent-model

Comment: No, the linked article is about polymorphic relations. This one is not.

Answer (score 0):

Bascially, you have 1 Model for 1 Database Table (except the Table is an intermediate table (pivot table)).

So shortly, yes. If you want Eloquent Models to work properly, you need to create a Model for your E-Mail Table.